# Should Container be cleared on every search?

Tags: solrnet

I am not very familiar with Solr Search, but the following code which some contractors are doing for us looks very wrong to me:

```
    public ActionResult SearchLiveTraining(string searchText, string locationsID)
    {
        // irrelevant code...

        //clean Container
        Startup.Container.Clear();
        Startup.InitContainer();

        // irrelevant code...
    }
```

The thing that seems very strange to me is that Startup is static class and this seems like the sort of calls that should be made once at the beginning of the application... not once for every search.

I am also concerned about whether even though this works fine in testing, if in production when many people are using the page at a time if this will cause problems?

Are my fears justified and should I immediately look to correct this, or is this actually how solr search is intended to work?

Comment: indeed that code is wrong. See https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Initialization.md#initialization for reference.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Please see my new question on this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49047860/is-changing-core-url-going-to-be-an-issue-with-multiple-users-searching-simultan